# Run more than one thread using ScheduledExecutorService with same period

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the ability to work with more than one server in my application. And for each server I need to fetch some info from server into decoupled thread with period in one second.

How to start more than one `Runnable` with `ScheduledExecutorService`? Should I use an exclusive executor for each thread, or I can use one executor instance and pass to it all of my runnables that needs to be run each second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you're looking for is [`ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)):

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period; that is executions will commence after `initialDelay` then `initialDelay+period`, then `initialDelay + 2 * period`, and so on.

Here's a simple example:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // runnable logic           
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You should use one `ExecutorService` in your application. See the Javadocs for more information about the method.

Comment: Each second I need to run `FetchInfoRunnable` for each server. For example I have 4 servers, so I need to run 4 threads each seconds. So I need to run `executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new FetchInfoRunnable(server), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` 4 times?

Comment: Yes one schedule call for each server.